# Remove Screen Capture from Video Device Type

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-encoder

in Microsoft.Expression.Encoder is it possible to remove Screen capture from Video device type.

If I do

```
VideoDevices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video);
```

It returns me 2 device ( The webcam plugged in and the Screen capture )

Tho i don't want the ability to use Screen Capture as the recording device.

Should i just remove it manually while checking the name of it, or did they add some kind of functionnality to only get webcam devices in video devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, filtering according to a string match seems to be your best choice.

Either filter for the name "Screen Capture Source" or the fact that it's `DevicePath` does not contain the substring "usb".